# C# lock does not make my variable private

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, locking

I need to keep my variable "counter" private for each thread.

I tried to use :

```
object locker = new object();
private object locker = new object(); 
private static readonly object locker = new object();
```

But neither of them works.

Is there any other way I use to solve this problem?

Here is my code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    int counter = 0;
    private static readonly object locker = new object();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Task t1 = new Task(() =>
        {
            func();
        });
        Task t2 = new Task(() =>
        {
            func();
        });
        // two threads
        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
    }

    void func()
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            counter++;
            Console.Write(counter + " "); // prints "1 2"
                                          // it should print "1 1"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason you can't just move `counter` to inside `func`?

Comment: The thread-locking variable is not the problem. This is exactly what the expected output is - you just made the `counter` variable thread-safe. It can only ever be incremented by one thread at once, which is why it gives `1 2`. If you remove your safeguards (i.e. the `lock(..)`), the output will become unpredictable and maybe output `1 1`, because now two threads may read and write to the same variable at the same time. `counter` is a **global** variable with respect to the class, and not a thread-local variable.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt I think you mean a class-level variable. C# has no global variables.

Comment: Not clear what you want to *achieve*. Indeed `lock` does not make variable `private` as there is no relations between those two concepts...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look at this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.priority(v=vs.110).aspx

```
[ThreadStatic]
static long threadCount = 0;
```

I think this will help you.